# Inserting Elements into a List in Python

Tags: python

I've across the following code:

```
b = [4,5,6] 
b[-1:-1] = [5] 
print b
```

Which Outputs:

`b = [4,5,5,6]`

To try and understand what was happening, I change the 2nd line to `b[-1:-2]`,`b[-1:-3]` and found that the `b` that gets printed is still the same. I don't really understand what the 2nd line does.

Also, when I change `b[-1:-1] = 5`, an Error occurs and I'm unclear why this is the case.

Thank You

Comment: basically the [] notation accesses a slice of the list, whereas negative integers give the number from the end of the list. 
The error is, because you have to assign itterables and in this case b[-1:-1]=b[-1:-2]=[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classical string/array slicing problem.
When you do `b[-1:-1]` it says get me a string from second last element to second last element which is empty in this case.And assign/replace that list with a new list [5].

Same goes for other options.

The last statement

```
  b[-1:-1]=5
```

says get me a list and assign it an elememt. So a type mismatch occurs throwing you an error.

Comment: But shouldn't using `b[-1:-3] =  [5]` give me an error, as I'm looking to put a single element into a string containing 2 elements? I don't understand how that part works.

Comment: Split always works from left to right and 1st argument to that should be less that the second else an empty list is returned. So b[-1:-3] says get me a string starting from second last index to fourth last index but since the 2nd argument is smaller empty list is returned. Instead if u write b[-3,-1] it will give u 2 elements